# How to Autowire in Junit Tests (General Newb Enquiry)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

This is a general question about Spring and creating application contexts.

I am working on a unit test for an web site application.  The website uses Spring and Hibernate and I want to test with some data from the database.  I do not know how to connect the Spring IOC container to my unit tests.  I know where the applicationContext.xml lives, but how do I get access to its beans in unit tests?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.test;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class SessionFactoryTest {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testSessionFactoryAutowiring() {
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Assert.assertEquals(session.getClass(),Session.class);
    }
}
```

Which generates the error

```
Testsuite: com.example.test.SessionFactoryTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec

Testcase: testSessionFactoryAutowiring took 0.002 sec
Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.test.SessionFactoryTest.testSessionFactoryAutowiring(SessionFactoryTest.java:19)
```

Now my question is, how do I get access to the sessionFactory from the normal applicationContex.xml?  How do I get access to the container?  I dont mind creating my own, but by the end of today I would really love to be writing unit tests.  Who wouldn't?

UPDATE:  I did add the annotations according to the Spring documentation to my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
```

But the file cannot be found and I do not know how to specify the file relative to my test.

```
Testsuite: com.example.test.SessionFactoryTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.045 sec

Testcase: testSessionFactoryAutowiring took 0.035 sec
Caused an ERROR
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
```

The structure of my project looks like:

```
src/
web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
test/java/com/example/SessionFactoryTest.java
```

And is built with ant.

Answer (score 0):

Using classpath in locations will not work because you're not using default location for applicationContext.xml

But this will probably work.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "src/stuff web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
public class SessionFactoryTest {
```

I suppose that you have this in your application context file also:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.example.SessionFactoryImpl" />
```

Comment: I did try that in the form `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})` but that did not work.

Comment: I was able to set the classpath in ant for the scope of the test execution.  But I still am not able to instantiate the bean.  Ideas?

Comment: Could you please paste how you're application context look like also?

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a spring test context and annotate with @Runwith. the xml comes to src/test/resources/my-test-config.xml

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:my-test-config.xml"})
public class myTest { ...
```

Edit: I am not sure but i guess you need to add the hibernate jar to the classpath in your test scope too

Comment: Can you please rephrase "the xml comes to"?  I'm having a hard time parsing that.

Comment: the 'usual' project structure looks like this

Comment: Im sorry that still doesn't make sense to me, I am trying to figure out how to specify the location of the applicationContext.xml in the `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {})` annotation. Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: you need a testresource folder in your project. By convention you put files that you need in your unit tests to src/test/resources and your unittests in src/test/java

Comment: Do you build with maven?

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but I get this error `exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]`  but clearly I do have one in the context `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">`

Comment: I wish I did, but no, I am forced to use ant.

Comment: I just looked up the doc, try to prefix with 'file:' e.g. @ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"}) http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/AbstractContextLoader.html#modifyLocations(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...)

Answer (score 0):

I set the classpath to include the web directory in my ant build.xml and now the applicationContext.xml is found.  Now I have other issues.  IN particular the jndi reference in the main applicationContext.xml.  All said and done, this was the resulting ant task

```
<target name="test-platform" depends="compile_tests">
    <mkdir dir="${platform.test.log.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="true" haltonerror="true">
        <classpath refid="test.build.classpath"/>
        <classpath location="test"/>
        <classpath location="${build_testclassdir}"/>
        <batchtest todir="${platform.test.log.dir}">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="true"/>
            <fileset dir="${javatests}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Then in one of my tests

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:resources/test-applicationContext.xml"})
```

And placed a test context in the test/resources directory

```
[david@david web]$ ll test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 4851 Apr  9 16:02 test/resources/test-applicationContext.xml
```

Comment: Edit your post and include the issues and applicationcontext content. By the way, unit tests shouldn't have any dependencies, therefore you should mock the dependencies. You could use EasyMock for that purpose. You're trying to do integration testing.

Comment: Henrik, great point.  The test I needed to write was specifically to test the behavior of a certain method against all existing, real life data in a certain table in the database.

Comment: which errors do you get? and applicationcontext content?

Comment: Henrik, thanks for the reply.  Everything is working now, (and my CTO is happy which is cool).  As I mention in the answer to which this is a comment I needed to basically do 3 things, 1. create an ant target and set the classpath to include the test directory.  2.  add Transaction, RunWith and ContextConfiguration annotations on the test class with a location pointing to a test-applicationContext.xml.  3.  setup a org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource in the application context to not rely on jndi. Finally this allowed me to Autowire a sessionFactory in my test class, which was the goal. Ya

Answer (score 0):

For your example code you should be testing the return values from SessionFactory in the session factory unit test.

If you want to inject dependencies in a unit test consider using something like MockitoAnnotations to automatically inject mock objects to your class under test